# Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv on linux server

Tags: django, linux, ffmpeg, pydub

I installed ffmpeg and pydub successfully on my linux server.
And test with python environment ok.
[image: image run code on python env]

But when i running my code on nginx + gunicorn + django, its alert with error `/home/www/env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`
Someone can help me ?

Comment: Need more details, edit your question and post nginx and gunicorn configurations.

Comment: Show us results of command `which ffmpeg` and `which avconv`